# How to generate record index of a select query?

Tags: mysql

Before marking my question as a duplicate please be noticed that my case is very different.

```
SELECT
 c.id
 c.date_added AS date_added,
 @INDEX := @INDEX + 1 AS row_index
FROM
 cases c
JOIN (SELECT @INDEX := 0) indexer
LEFT JOIN users u ON c.owner_id = u.id
INNER JOIN case_profiles cases_id ON c.id = cases_id.cases_id

WHERE
 cases_id.`name` LIKE '%case%'
ORDER BY
 c.date_added DESC
```

It produces my row_index backwards 3,2,1 instead of expected 1,2,3, this happens only if I add inside WHERE any condition from columns of JOIN tables like cases_id.{COLUMN}.

Please help me overcome this problem
Thank you in advance!

Comment: use ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: row_number() is available on 8.0

Comment: Thank you for answers. For anyone who lands here,  I tried this window function on MariaDb 10.2 was very inefficient on big data sets.

Answer (score 0):

It happens like that with your query because of the sorting; the data are first joined before sorted. Try this:

```
SELECT A.*, @INDEX := @INDEX + 1 AS row_index
FROM
(SELECT
 c.id
 c.date_added AS date_added
FROM
 cases c
LEFT JOIN users u ON c.owner_id = u.id
INNER JOIN case_profiles cases_id ON c.id = cases_id.cases_id
WHERE
 cases_id.`name` LIKE '%case%'
ORDER BY
 c.date_added DESC) A JOIN (SELECT @INDEX := 0) indexer;
```

See [MySQL row_number, This Is How You Emulate It](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/)

Comment: In your suggested scenario it will no longer respect ORDER BY date_added DESC. Thank for your response anyway